# Range-based for loop and std::vector.push_back() crashing the program

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 42; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(i);
        vec.push_back(-i);
    }
    for (int x: vec) {
        for (int y: vec) {
            vec.push_back(x + y);
        }
    }
    for (int x: vec) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
}
```

What's causing this code to crash? I tried compiling it with -fsanitize=address, got `==9347==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x61500000fdb4 at pc 0x00010a4f1043 bp 0x7fff55710b70 sp 0x7fff55710b68`. It fails at `vec.push_back(x + y)` when x == 0 and y == 22 on my computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) :

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Range-based for loop uses iterators internally. Using `push_back` may cause these iterators to be invalidated.

Edit : Notice that when `y == 22` you are inserting a 65th element into your vector. It's likely the capacity was 64. Many implementations increase capacity by powers of 2 (doubling it each time).

Comment: Doing a push_back is UB inside any range for loop or inside nested range for loop ? (your answer makes me believe "any range for loop" but that would be such a pitfall)

Comment: @user You can't do anything that invalidates iterators to a vector you are iterating over using a range-based for loop. The rules for invalidation are quite explicit. For example, you can `push_back` inside the loop provide you are certain that `size()` will never exceed `capacity()` (for example by using `reserve()` to sufficiently increase capacity ahead of time). See each of [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)'s method's page for detailed invalidation rules. Yes, it's quite the pitfall!

Comment: Thank you for the precision

Comment: @user I would like to clarify that this problem is not unique to `std::vector`.  It's a problem many of the containers face. For example `std::deque::erase` or `std::unordered_map::insert` may invalidate iterators.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: You may check this other related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518970/why-is-it-unsafe-to-call-push-back-in-a-for-loop-even-when-there-is-no-memory-re

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `std::vector::push_back` or most `non-const` function for that matter the iterators are invalidated (When the new size exceeds the current capacity of the vector which causes the memory to be re-allocated internally)

You can find some good references on how standard containers or iterators work in general. I hope that gets you started!

Comment: There are non-const methods that never invalidate iterators. For example [std::vector::pop_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) or [std::vector::back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux or std::vector::data for that matter. It's a good rule of thumb though in my opinion. Most non-const methods except methods that give direct references to the data.