# C++ vector initialise a vector of agents for a genetic algorithm

Tags: c++, vector, genetic-algorithm

I have the following C++ code, but I get some errors in mainly stuff like the following (after the block of code) the Agent is just a class that I created in a seperate file

```
vector<Agent> population;
for (vector<int>::iterator i = population.begin(); i != population.end(); ++i) {
    population.push_back(new Agent(generateDna(targetString.size())));
}
```

I get the following errors

> 1. no suitable user-defined conversion from "__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator>>" to "__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator>>" exists
>
> 2.no operator "!=" matches these operands -- operand types are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator>> != __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator>>
>
> 3.no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Tp=Agent, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (Agent *) -- object type is: std::vector>

and I'm new to c++ so these things might be self explanatory, but I don't know what they mean.

Comment: Unrelated: `vector<Agent>` stores `Agent`. `new Agent` provides `Agent *`. You probably don't want to `new`, but  also see if `emplace_back` is an option.

Comment: `vector<int>::iterator` is not the type for a `vector<Agent>`

Comment: BTW, don't iterate through a container while you are modifying it. The iterators become invalid.

Comment: Your design will encounter the problem described by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448274/range-based-for-loop-and-stdvector-push-back-crashing-the-program). Or it would, if not for the fact that your loop will never execute (`population` is initially empty).

Comment: I am trying to understand the purpose of this code. Why are you trying to iterate over an empty vector? Or is this just a bad example and population actually is not empty?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are iterating over collection in which you append during the cycle and even through iterator which is defined as int instead of Agent. Create new vector and push your generated values into this new vector.

Also be aware of using new keyword. You must dealocate that memory later.

Solution:

```
vector<Agent> population;
vector<Agent> newPopulation;
for (vector<Agent>::iterator i = population.begin(); i != population.end(); ++i) {
    newPopulation.push_back(Agent(generateDna(targetString.size())));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I though an iterator would be an integer just like a index of an array... I think this solves the problem in my code thank you for the help

Comment: @MartinSigNørbjerg No, iterator must know how much space it has to move on to the next item. So imagine that Agent has 30 bytes and int is 4 bytes. If you needed to move on to the next Agent, you would need to skip current 30 bytes but you were actualy skipping just 4 bytes which would cause memory conflict

Answer (score -2):

Your current compilation issue is that you're trying to store a `std::vector<Agent>::iterator` into a `std::vector<int>::iterator`. These are two completely different types.

Then there's your runtime issue (after you actually add elements to your container because right now you have none), your iterators might be invalidated after a `push_back` and you'll have UB because you're modifying the container while you're looping over it.

Then there's the issue where you're trying to store an `Agent*` into a vector of `Agent`'s.

---

All in all:

```
std::vector<Agent> population;

//fill your vector.. otherwise loop is useless because size is 0..
auto size = population.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    population.push_back(Agent(generateDna(targetString.size())));
}
```

Comment: I am still not sure if the intended operations is for every `Agent` in population we add a second generated `Agent`.

Comment: Unsure what the dv is for, step forward you cuties.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, might be so. I suppose only the OP knows that answer. This answer just tries to correct the code shown in question.

Comment: Keep them coming